# My POST postman request is being redirected to a GET

Tags: postman

I am trying to send a POST request to an endpoint but for some reason I am being automatically redirected to a GET to the same endpoint.

[image]

What I don't understand is if I copy the cURL and send it directly in terminal I wont be redirected to the GET call.

I have tried switching off "Automatic Redirects" in the settings but it doesnt help as the call wont be accepted at all.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use the `Follow original HTTP Method` option in the Request Settings.

> Redirect with the original HTTP method instead of the default behavior of redirecting with GET.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hi please check  enable interceptor **(Then, you can intercept the redirect response, extract what is interested, and set it as global variable or environment variable:)**  or delete cookie and check redirect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Pay attention to the screenshot - the POST request is sent to HTTP, but the next GET request is already redirected to HTTPS. Try sending a POST request to HTTPS. This is exactly what helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem. The problem was in SSL. Changed http to https it works as expected. May be it will help you. Good luck.